# Does mod_dav_svn support the Apache mpm-worker module?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mpm-worker, mod-dav-svn

Does the subversion mod_dav_svn support Apache's MPM-Worker thread configuration?

I'm finding very little documentation so far on this, and I'm looking for better ways to make use of my subversion server resources.

Information I could find is from 2002
http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2002-11/0463.shtml

Comment: if you have many subversion repos running on Apache 2.4 with mpm_worker you will run in a thread problem.

Answer (score 1):

It does. I'm using mpm worker on debian 6 in production environment without any problem.

Comment: Curious to know the approach you took to balance thread/server count.  We find a high number of servers to quickly consume all memory, but a high thread to /server ratio performs dead slow.  We had 512 max clients, 2 servers, 256 threads.   But looks like a 400/20/20 may be better ratio for our 3vcpu/6g/RHEL6 machine.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface it looks like it does, the easiest way to find out is to build/install apache as mpm-worker, and if the module loads and works as it should then yes it is thread safe.